# Foreach Loop echo group error

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach

Here I have a foreach loop going through a calendar of dates viewable by the client. On the first loop i pass $i as a variable equal to 0. Then i give the rules stating that if $i is equal to 0 or is divisible by 3 then to echo the div class group. However if the loop exits when $i is equal to 1 or is divisible by 2 to close the class group and continue down the html. For some reason when I have 1 or two entries the group does not close correctly and the following div is captured inside. Will you please look at this code to see where im messing up...

```
    <div class = "calender_dates">
<div class = 'calender_select'>
    <div class = 'dates past active'></div>
    <div class = "dates future"></div>
</div>
<div class = "past_events grid-calender">
    <?php $i=0 ?>
@foreach($past as $event)
<?php if($i==0 OR is_int($i/3)){
        if($i==0){
            echo '<div class="group_loop_first">';
        } else{
            echo '<div class="group_loop">';
        }

              } ?>
   <div class = "p_date grid-date">
        <div class = 'date_head'>
            <div class = "head_img">
                <p>img</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "head_description">
                <p>{{$event->caption}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "date_foot">
            <div class = "foot_date">
                <p class = "day">
                    {{$event->publish_at->format('d')}}
                </p>


                <p class = "month">
                    {{$event->publish_at->format('M')}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class = "foot_callout">
                <p class = "name">{{$event->name}}</p>
                <p>{{$event->address}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $i++ ?>
    <?php if($i==0 OR is_int($i/3)){
            echo '</div>';
        }?>
    @endforeach
     <?php
        if($i==1 OR $i==2 OR is_int($i/2)){
                echo '</div>';
            }?>
</div>

<div class = "future_events grid-calender">
    <?php $i=0 ?>
@foreach($future as $event)
<?php if($i==0 OR is_int($i/3)){
                  echo '<div class="group_loop">';
              } ?>
   <div class = "p_date grid-date">
        <div class = 'date_head'>
            <div class = "head_img">
                <p>img</p>
            </div>
            <div class = "head_description">
                <p>{{$event->caption}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "date_foot">
            <div class = "foot_date">
                    <p class = "day">
                        {{$event->publish_at->format('d')}}
                    </p>


                    <p class = "month">
                        {{$event->publish_at->format('M')}}
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div class = "foot_callout">
                <p class = "name">{{$event->name}}</p>
                <p>{{$event->address}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $i++ ?>
    <?php if($i==0 OR is_int($i/3)){
                echo '</div>';
            }?>
    @endforeach
    <?php
    if($i==1 OR is_int($i/2)){
            echo '</div>';
        }?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Should this be inside php tags? `<?php @foreach($past as $event){ ?>` same for `<?php @endforeach ?>` ?

Comment: <?php @endforeach; } ?>  sorry I was too slow editing comment! note missing `{ }` and `;`

Comment: To check whether `$i` is divisible by 2 or not, use `$i % 2 == 0`, and similarly to check whether `$i` is divisible by 3 or not, use `$i % 3 == 0`.

Comment: Likewise `<?php @foreach($future as $event){ ?> ` and `<?php @endforeach;} ?>`  You don't really need to drop in and out of php tags so often. You can just stay in one pair for a block of code.

Comment: These also seem to be outside of php as well `{{$event->caption}}` and the others. I would have expected `<?php echo $event->caption; ?>`

Comment: In general use @if blade directives so you don't need to use <?php tags for if statements.

Comment: @Steve The `@foreach`, `@endforeach`, and `{{ }}` statements are Laravel's Blade templating syntax. They should not be inside php tags.

Comment: Oops sorry - working in the wrong language, should have realised!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into issues because you're prematurely incrementing your counter. The code below is cleaned up a bit, but the basic idea is you shouldn't increment your counter until after you've checked if you need the closing div tag.

```
<div class="past_events grid-calender">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    @foreach($past as $event)
        @if ($i == 0)
    <div class="group_loop_first">
        @elseif ($i % 3 === 0)
    <div class="group_loop">
        @endif
        <div class = "p_date grid-date">
            <!-- rest of html -->
        </div>

        @if ($i % 3 === 0)
    </div>
        @endif
        <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="future_events grid-calender">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    @foreach($future as $event)
        @if ($i % 3 === 0)
    <div class="group_loop">
        @endif
        <div class = "p_date grid-date">
            <!-- rest of html -->
        </div>
        @if ($i % 3 === 0)
    </div>
        @endif
        <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up! I wasn't to sure on the blade template stuff.